# Global name __file__ is not defined?

Tags: python, jython

I'm bukkit plugin coder and I'm stuck on making config file. I want to use `__file__` to locate current directory of .py file... I was googling and saw `sys.argv[0]`, but as I see, it's only for Windows users, I want it to be compatible for every OS, if I'm wrong, can you provide me example of it?

Here's my code:

```
def onEnable(self):
    pluginlokacija1 = os.path.realpath(__file__)
    if os.path.isfile("%s/Halloween/config.yml"%pluginlokacija1):
        pass
    else:
        os.mkdir("%s/Halloween/"%pluginlokacija1)
        self.createConfig()
        self.findFolder()
        self.cfg = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(File(os.path.join(self.folder,"config.yml")))
        itemlist = self.cfg.getString("main.itemlist")
        print ("Rezultat: %s" % itemlist)

def createConfig(self):
    pluginlokacija2 = os.path.realpath(__file__)
    fo = open("%s/Halloween/config.yml"%pluginlokacija2, "wb")
    fo.write( "main:\n itemlist: 172\n candydropchance: 50");
    fo.close
```

Error:

```
14:54:06 [SEVERE] Error occurred while enabling Halloween v1.0 (Is it up to date
?): null
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<iostream>", line 70, in onEnable
NameError: global name '__file__' is not defined
```

Thanks for answering! :)

Comment: You are wrong. And both `sys.argv[0]` and `__file__` won't work when you are in the interactive shell. You need to run the file from the command line in order to use that.

Comment: @InbarRose Thanks for answering, but I'm not really sure about what are you talking about... Since I'm pretty new to python, can you provide me some docs or examples? Thanks!

Comment: Inbar assumes that you are executing code which is not in a file, hence the variable `__file__` isn't existing.  This can happen if you start Python interactively (by typing `python` in a shell) and then try to use `__file__` in the interactive console.

Comment: both `sys.argv[0]` and `__file__` work on windows and linux, (tested) and I am pretty sure also mac (though I have never personally done that). HOWEVER - they only work when you run your Python script/file from a command line or from the shell. If you are running in an interactive program like Idle, then it won't work.

Comment: @InbarRose is there any another way to do that if I'm running it in an interactive program?

Comment: why you need locate py-file?

Comment: @MichaelKazarian Because I need to make new folder which will contain config, inside same foldere where is py-file located...

Comment: Interactive program is not supposed to be used for running your script. It is used for testing etc. Once the script is inside its own lovely and comfortable file, all nested in its comfy directory, THEN you run it, and then it will work perfectly as you want it to. The interactive shell is not where you want to be running your scripts from.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I've made it using os.getcwd() method...

Answer (score 1):

> Because I need to make new folder which will contain config, inside same foldere where is py-file located

The simple answer is, this isn't "the UNIX way."  Nor is it the Mac OS way.

The "UNIX way" is to put your configuration file(s) with all the other configuration files in an "etc" directory, such as /etc, or /usr/local/etc, and look for them there.  Note: the 'package manager' should be able to install the application where with system administrator wants it, your code has to be smart enough to find it wherever it gets put.  This can vary a lot, especially across Linux distros.

The "Mac OS way" is to put the configuration files in your "App Bundle," a directory structure that includes your program, an icon image for your application, and any other configuration files, message catalogs, etc, required by program.  User-modifiable configuration files, if you have any, go in ~/Library/Application Support/{your program name here}.  You can look at some of these on a Mac by starting the Terminal application and

```
$ cd /Application/Preview.app
```

This is the "app bundle" for Preview, the PDF-and-picture viewer.  There are a bunch of sub-directories here:

```
$ find . -type d | wc -l
     107
```

Go have a look around.  You'll find a number of .plist files, which are Property Lists, typically XML configuration files for various parts of the app.

The long answer is stop trying to force your application to follow common Windows usage if you want to it to truly be "compatible for every OS."

Answer (score 1):

Python Shell doesn't detect current file path in `__file__`.
If you put `__file__` in a python file `test.py` and the run `test.py`, then it will work well.

Answer (score 0):

`Because I need to make new folder which will contain config, inside same foldere where is py-file located`

Because config is system specific part (`/etc` for unix, registry for win) it's good way to use other tools for it. It may be instalation scenario or create config for first run. If you use jython use [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) for your settings. This way need because enduser can haven't permissions for create directory or you can have problems with support config in future.
Upon your problem it work for me on python2.7 and jython2.5.3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, os
print sys.argv[0]
print os.path.realpath(__file__)
```

Result:

```
$ jython test.py
/home/miha/tmp/11/test.py
/home/miha/tmp/11/test.py
```

May be you overloaded `__file__` in other part of your code?

Answer (score -1):

Afaik there is no real reliable way to get binary name with path. Even on Windows this may file in certain scenarios usually when run from atypical network shares like VPNs.

On Linux one can look up in /proc/self/exe, on newer freebsd (6+?)  a sysctl with KERN_PROC_PATHNAME. Afaik there is no way on OS X.  If it fails, it only displays the filename, without PATH.

I'm not Python inclined, so I can't provide examples.